# Nhibernate Cascade

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, cascade

What does ***Cascade*** in [Nhibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) mean?

I see a lot of options in cascading:

- Delete
- All
- AllDeleteOrphan
- DeleteOrphan
- SaveUpdate

Can you explain these with with examples and their distinctions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It means apply the action to an item's related items.

Please see: [NHibernate Cascades: the different between all, all-delete-orphans and save-update](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/NHibernateCascadesTheDifferentBetweenAllAlldeleteorphansAndSaveupdate.aspx):

> - none - do not do any cascades, let
>     users handle them by themselves.
> - save-update - when the object is
>     saved/updated, check the associations
>     and save/update any object that
>     requires it (including save/update the
>     associations in many-to-many
>     scenario).
> - delete - when the object
>     is deleted, delete all the objects in
>     the association.
> - delete-orphan -
>     when the object is deleted, delete all
>     the objects in the association. In
>     addition, when an object is
>     removed from the association and not
>     associated with another object
>     (orphaned), also delete it.
> - all - when an object is save/update/delete,
>     check the associations and
>     save/update/delete all the objects found.
> - all-delete-orphan - when an object is
>     save/update/delete, check the associations and
>     save/update/delete all the objects found. In
>     additional to that, when an object is removed
>     from the association and not associated with
>     another object (orphaned), also delete it.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between all and all-delete-orphan could you please explain?

Comment: @JonathanO if you choose all and then you remove an association it will only remove the association not the associated object.
if you choose all-delete-orphan than it will remove associated object too.