# C# Delete problem with an object relating to another object

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, architecture, entity-relationship

We have two assemblies A and B where B extends from A.
B has a property of a type in A

If we have a record of B in de database and we delete A wich is used by B the record will be removed

How can we prevent this in code because we will show a delete link or not if we can or can't delete A.
Because B always need a type of A and if A is in used by a record of B, A may not be removed.

We use NHibernate as ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check relations in sql
Or triggers witch you can use for prevent deleting

And for the delete link i think you must check into the code and write a method for it

Answer (score 2):

Use the cascade feature in the ORM, and exploit it properly
You might Read [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994433/nhibernate-cascade) in the forum first.