# Will NHibernate unnecessarily update objects when the cascade save-update attribute is set?

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994433/nhibernate-cascade) explains the save-update option for the cascade attribute in NHibernate as follows:

> save-update - when the object is saved/updated, check the associations and save/update **any object that requires it** (including save/update the associations in many-to-many scenario).

Does it mean that NHibernate keeps track of objects that were modified and need to be updated in the database when an associated object triggers a database operation or that NHibernate simply updates everybody regardless of modifications being made to them?

I'm trying to find out what is the exact meaning of the **"requires"** word in that sentence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate **always** keeps track of modified objects; this is not related to cascade.

*requires* in this context means basically that transient objects that are referenced will be saved when the referencing object is saved/updated.

Comment: I've configured NHibernate to show me its SQL output and it indeed behaved as you said when everything was done within a single **Session**, but in my tests NHibernate hasn't kept track of modified objects across **Sessions** and it issued unnecessary SQL Update commands for everybody!

Comment: Well, of course it doesn't track across sessions. That's not how it's designed to work; the Session is the **Unit of Work**. Reattaching objects to a different session is *supported*, but that's not the ideal workflow.